# writing android sensor data to XML file

Tags: android, xml, events, android-activity, sensors

hi
i am developing an application that read data from sensors and write those data to an XML file when you press a key. 
i have 2 activity one for button and another is an Activity who implements sensorEventListener.
the problem is my main activity is button and couldn't get data from event listener activity.
i think the listener activity is not active but when i create an intent and start activity with that intent the program stop working. the button is able to create XML file solely.
so how could i read sensor data from sensors,and how to send them to XML file when the button got clicks ?

thanks

Comment: i am interested in reading the sensors as well. is there a chance you can share your code ? (i am not android/java expert and having a some code to start from  will be great)

Answer (score 1):

From what u described I think it might be best to have a single activity (with the button to start) and have this activity listening to the sensor values all the time while storing the latest entry in memory.

In the `onResume` method of your you might want to register the listener (this). Don't forget to `unRegister`, once you leave/pause the activity.

Once you press the button, write out the cached sensor values into your XML file.

Comment: i do onResume and unRegister stuff and they are OK, and the one activity idea is not work i try it.how could you have one sensorEventListener activity and button in same class?

Comment: i am going to explain more detailed. i have one activity(sensoeEm extend activity implement sensorEventListener) that read data from sensors(proximity,light,orientation...) and i have another activity (btn extend activity) who implement a  button onClickListener, so i want when the button get clicked read the data and write them to XML

Comment: I think it might help, yes. The key difference is that you don't trigger the READ, but always read and store the latest value. Once you click on the button, simply write the values out.